# Anime show where the main character (and main villain) are reincarnations of warrior gods

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm looking for the name of a fantasy adventure anime where the main character is supposed to be the reincarnation of some warrior God and so was the main villain?

Comment: Echoing Darjeeling's comment, **you need to provide more detail** (when & where did you watch it, language, characters detail, setting, etc) before reposting on that site, because with current detail, this is almost impossible to be answered.

Comment: On account of there being basically no details in this question, I'm not going to kick this over to [scifi.se].

Comment: @senshin - This is probably answerable, tbh. Kick it over

Comment: @Valorum If you say so. Here you go.

Comment: @senshin - Ta-da!

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like [Hero Tales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_Tales) (Jūshin Enbu).

The main protagonist (Taitō Shirei) is the reincarnation of a warrior god named alkaid. His opponent Keirō is the reincarnation of the celestial war-god dubhe

Comment: Dude.... If this is right you are awesome.